# Maxima and minima in case of 4 variable venn diagrams

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does one approach/solve for maxima and minima in case of 4 variable set theory questions such as these :

The following table gives the information regarding the games liked by the students in a school. Each student in the school likes at least one game.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ag2S.png)

A – number of boys who like that game.

B – number of girls who like that game.

C – number of students who like only that game.

1.What is the maximum possible number of students in the school?

2.What is the minimum possible number of boys in the school?

3.What is the range of the possible number of girls in the school?

4.If there are 380 students in the school, then the least possible number of boys who like only basketball is?

Thanks!

Comment: It is always appreciated when you also mention what have you have tried, or what you know so far, FYI. Also FYI, people on this site *hate* external links to problem-relevant info. Might do you better to type that in, annoying though it may be.